# read docx files in a directory and concat the content together in node?

Tags: node.js, file, docx

the code is required to read all the files in a directory and return all the content in the each docx file of this directory.

i am using glob and mammoth library to read the directory and docx file respectively. However I want to concat each file content together into a bigger content. but since node is asynchronous, the code I made will pass me the empty content before reading each file.

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");
var glob = require("glob");
function readAllFiles(dir){

  var data_collection = '';
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    // reading the directory
    glob(dir,  function (er, files) { 
      console.log(files);
      // for each file in the directory read its content
      _.map(files, function(file){
        mammoth.extractRawText({path: file})
            .then(function(result){
                var text = result.value; // The raw text
                var messages = result.messages;
                text = text.replace(/(^[ \t]*\n)/gm, "").replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '');
                console.log('extractRawText',text);
                // concat the small content into big content
                data_collection = data_collection + " "+text;
            })
            .done();
      });
      resolve(data_collection);
    });
  });
}
```

how would I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you considered `fs.readFileSync` instead of `mammoth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.map is synchronous. It does not wait for the mammoth promises to resolve. The line `resolve(data_collection);` will be executed immediately after `_.map` and before the mammoth promises resolve. That is why data_collection is empty.

You can use something like,

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");
var glob = require("glob");

function readAllFiles(dir){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    glob(dir, (err, files) => {
      if(err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      return Promise.all(files.map((file) => mammoth.extractRawText({ path: file })))
        .then((results) => {
          let data = ''
          results.forEach((result) => {
            const value = result.value.replace(/(^[ \t]*\n)/gm, "").replace('\r', '')
            data = data.concat(value)
          })
          resolve(data)
        })
        .catch(reject)
    })
  })
}

async function test() {
  const data = await readAllFiles('./test/**/*.docx') // All my docx files are in the test directory
  console.log(data) // Print data
}

test()
```

Note that this would execute mammoth.extractRawText function calls in parallel. If you need to limit the number of simultaneous parallel calls, you can use something like [async.mapLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit).